# Is it possible to make headings text bold while export to csv using fputcsv?

Tags: php, export, export-to-csv, fputcsv

I am working on export to csv sheet requirement, Its working fine data is getting exported to CSV sheet but all the data including titles on top of the sheet for each column and normal data exported as a normal text. What I want here is obviously all the titles should be in bold text. Is it possible to export all titles in bold colour?

My code:

```
$list[] = 'Title-1,Title-2,Title-3,Title-4'; // I want these titles in bold text
foreach ($result as $ck => $user_data) {
  $list[] = $user_data['val-1'] . ',' . $user_data['val-2'] . ',' . $user_data['val-3']. ',' . $user_data['val-4'];
}
ob_clean();
$fileName = 'file_name.csv';
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false);
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $fileName);
$file = fopen("contacts.csv", "w");
$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($list as $line) {
  fputcsv($file, explode(',', $line));
}
fclose($file);
exit;
```

some people are saying bold is not possible in CSV file & supports only plain text but it does, for your reference I am attaching a screenshot. please see it [image]

I am using 'fputcsv()' for export into csv sheet. Any help. Thanks.

Comment: CSV is a plain text file format. There's no such thing as "bold" in CSV.

Comment: There is an option bold in CSV file please refer my question as I updated it.

Comment: I don't see a CSV in your screenshot. I see a LibreOffice Calc file.

Comment: OK Thanks, Am sorry, If CSV doesn't support bold text, Does Excel file supports or not?

Comment: Microsoft Excel Open XML Format Spreadsheet, as well as older Excel formats, support it. Open/LibreOffice's OpenDocument Formats support it as well.

Comment: Could you please tell, how to achieve this?

Comment: If you plan on generating Excel files instead of CSVs, that's a significant step up in complexity. You can take a look at this library: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not possible to do so in CSV.
CSV is like a plain text without any formatting.